# Changing the default ActiveRecord id from 0 to 1000000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to change the minimum for the id of created objects from 1 to 1000.
So when I create in rails my first model object it gets the ID 1000 and not 1.

Is there a way to set this in the schema/migration files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familiar with MySQL, but for Postgres you can do something like this in your migration file:

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps

    end
    execute "SELECT setval('customers_id_seq', 1000);"
end
```

Note that the execute method call is made outside the create_table block.

Answer (score 4):

For MySQL use

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps

    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE customers AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;"
end
```

This will have your auto_increment field (id) start at value 1000.